# error while applying regex to numeric values to replace values in nifi

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

hi I have a data as below

```
[{
   s1 = 98493456645
   s2 = 0000000000
   102 = 93234,
   12 = 
   15 = rahdeshfui
   16 = 2343432,234234
  },
{
   s1 = 435234235
   s2 = 01
   102 = 45336
   12 = 
   15 = vjsfrh@gmail.com
   16 = 2415454
 }
 ]
```

now using reg expression i need to change to json format and i have tried this

regexp:- `([^\s]+?.*)=((.*(?=,$))+|.*).*`

replace value:- `"$1":"$2",`

for this values i am getting output as below

```
[{
   "s1":"98493456645",
   "s2":"0000000000",
   "102":"93234,",
   "12":"",
   "15":"rahdeshfui",
   "16":"2343432,234234",
  },
{
   "s1":"435234235",
   "s2":"01",
   "102":"45336",
   "12":"",
   "15":"vjsfrh@gmail.com",
   "16":"2415454"
 }
 ]
```

but I my expected output should be as below

```
[{
       "s1":98493456645,
       "s2":0,
       "102":93234,
       "12":"",
       "15":"rahdeshfui",
       "16":"2343432,234234",
      },
    {
       "s1":435234235,
       "s2":01,
       "102":45336,
       "12":"",
       "15":"vjsfrh@gmail.com",
       "16":"2415454"
     }
     ]
```

for numneric numbers their should not be in "" and if i have a value more than one 0 i need to replace it with single 0 and for some values i have `,` at end i need to skip `,` in case if i have one

Comment: You might do some more replacements afterwards as your replacement already wraps everything between double quotes.

Comment: As ugly as this already is, you could add `.replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"", "$1")`. This is Java, right? You might add the tag to your question.

Comment: Your regex is slightly flawed. Even if fixed, you have a complex replacement that requires another step. So, you'd need some kind of lambda replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bit cumbersome, but you want to replace multiple things so one option might be to use multiple replacements.

Note that these patterns do not take the opening `[{` and closing `]]` into account or any nesting but only the key value part as your posting pattern is for the example data.

**1.)** Wrap the keys and values in double quotes while not capturing the
    comma at the end and match the equals sign including the surrounding
    spaces:

`(\S+) = (\S*?),?(?=\n)` and replace with `"$1":"$2",`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF780p/1)

**2.)** Remove the double quotes around the digits except for those that start with 0:

`("[^"]+":)"(?!0+[1-9])(\d+)""` and replace with `$1$2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF780p/2)

**3.)** Remove the comma after the last key value:

`("[^"]+":)(\S+),(?!\n *"\w+")` and replace with `$1$2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF780p/3)

**4.)** Replace 2 or more times a zero with a single zero:

`("[^"]+":)0{2,}` and replace with `$10`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EF780p/4)

That will result in:

```
[{
   "s1":98493456645,
   "s2":0,
   "102":93234,
   "12":"",
   "15":"rahdeshfui",
   "16":"2343432,234234"
  },
{
   "s1":435234235,
   "s2":"01",
   "102":45336,
   "12":"",
   "15":"vjsfrh@gmail.com",
   "16":2415454
 }
 ]
```

Is assume the last value `"16":"2415454"` is `"16":2415454` as the value contains digits only.